# Can't insert images, gallery on WP portfolio post

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a website here: http://goo.gl/fPXuFN

I am using a WP theme but for some reason it won't show up the images or even gallery.

Try to tweak the codes but still can't find the issue.

Any idea? Would you like to check it exactly on the site?

[image]

You can inspect elements if you want or check the login details.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the inspect element , and in your style.css there was

```
#last-work img 
{
    display: none;
}
```

instead of that what i did is:

```
#last-work img 
{
    display: block;
}
```

and it worked for me.